# JQuery $.post response contain error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to post date from jquery post method to php server page. I'm getting the status as success, but data contain some html code with error

jquery code

```
$.post("admin_controller.php",{id: $('#myValue').val(),action: "details" },
        function(data,status){
            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

php code

```
$action_value = $_POST['action'];
switch($action_value) {
    case details:
        echo $_POST['id'];
    break;
    case view_all_customers:
        //$result = $c_play_info->get_all_customers();
        echo 'null';
    break;
}
```

output

Data: 
**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant details - assumed 'details' in **F:\Accel\projectselevanta\htdocs\127.www\gtet\admin_controller.php** on line **7**
18
Status: success

i can display the values without switch statement, when use switch statement it showing  above error. please help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your strings:

```
switch($action_value) {
    case 'details':
        echo $_POST['id'];
    break;
    case 'view_all_customers':
        //$result = $c_play_info->get_all_customers();
        echo 'null';
    break;
}
```

Comment: hi bro, i used to many times switch statement case  without quotes, but today only its happens why?

Comment: Maybe your other scripts have warnings disabled.

Comment: You can change the error reporting level with `error_reporting()`.

Comment: ya bro its correct. Due to the error_reporting() has only problem thanks mate